# React Native Animated Listener not triggered when offset is updated

Tags: animation, react-native

At the moment I have an animation that updates an offset and then flattens it at the end to reset for the next animation. I am listening for updates to this animation to coordinate with another but it's not being triggered when the offset is updated.

```
imagePosition.addListener(this._animateOther)
```

I would expect _animateOther to be triggered as my object moves.

However, this does not trigger _animateOther.

```
this.state.imagePosition.setOffset( update )
```

Only when the offset is merged back into the value does it trigger _animateOther.

```
this.state.imagePosition.flattenOffset()
```

Is this a bug and is there any way to listen to offset updates?

Answer (score 0):

Your `_animateOther` can only be trigged when the value is updated, not offset. You should try **[setValue](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.39/docs/animated.html#setvalue)** instead of setOffset.

`flattenOffset` merges the offset value into the base value and resets the offset to zero. The internal code looks like this:

```
flattenOffset() {
    this._value += this._offset;
    this._offset = 0;
}
```

It updates animation value, that why your `_animateOther` is triggered.

Comment: But the entire purpose of offset is so that I can do continued animations.

i.e. 
User drags square from (0,0) to (20, 5), lifts finger, then drags square from (20, 5) -> (30,10)

If I update the value every time they pan the square will end up at (10,5) as it resets on the next pan. If I only update offset and flatten at the end I'll end up at the correct (30,10) coordinate.

Comment: The trick is when you start moving your square (onResponderGrant in View or onPanResponderGrant in PanResponder), `setOffet` to animated value and `setValue` to 0, update the value every time you move your finger (onResponderMove), and flattenOffset when you lift finger (onResponderRelease).

Using PanResponder? [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/octopitus/edcf671ddea4f60b3794099bec304748)